# Python TypeError:unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

```
n = 2
board = [[0] * 2 ** n for i in range(2 ** n)]
rr = 1
rc = 1
currentNum=0

if n == 2:
    for i in board:
        for j in board:
            if board[rr + i][rc + j] == 0:
                board[rr + i][rc + j] = currentNum
    currentNum + 1
```

I am getting an error that says:
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I don't know much python but that should get i and j for the board like position
Board[rr+i][rc+j]
is there another way I should be doing this in python?

Edit: asked to post complete traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/***/***.py", line 10, in <module>
    if board[rr + i][rc + j] == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: please post the complete traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you from a C/C++ background? Normally in those languages you'd do for loops like: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, and each value of `i` would be the index.

In Python, however, when you do a for-loop you're iterating through each value of `board`. So in this case, `i` is actually each sublist in `board`.

You probably want to do:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        ...
```

Comment: Yes I am, that makes more sense to me! I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `i` is a sublist in `board`. And `rr` is an int, so when you try to do `rr + i`,you will get the error`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`.To get every index in `board`,you can use

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
n = 2
board = [[0] * 2 ** n for i in range(2 ** n)]
rr = 1
rc = 1
currentNum=0

if n==2:
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                board[i][j] = currentNum
            currentNum+=1
```